# I have been having trouble declaring the elements "RelativeLayout" and "Resources"

Tags: android, android-studio, element, mobile-application

I have been in the process of developing an app and I appear to be running into constant issues with certain tools. My most recent problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to declare the elements. Pictures of the error I receive is attached as well as the code for both.

[image: Relative Layout error]

[image: Resources error]

```
//////////////////////////////////////Code for the RelativeLayout Error////////////////////////////
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/background"
tools:context="emit.dev.androideatit.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>








//////////////////Code for the Resources Error//////////////////////////////
<Resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

 </Resources>
```

Thankyou for you assistance

Comment: `<Resources>` is a typo. That should be lowercase-`r` `<resources>`. The other issue may resolve itself after you fix that, and clean/rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test with deleting 
 `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />`

in Text view you are using in Relativelayout?

I think it's for constraint layout.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. However, it appears that even when I delete that portion it still gives me the element error. Also, the resources typo was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using RelativeLayout at the parent container and at the same time using ConstraintLayout attributes i.e.

//Error

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Either replace the RelativeLayout with ConstraintLayout or use RelativeLayout attributes:

**For ConstraintLayout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/background"
tools:context="emit.dev.androideatit.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**For RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/background"
tools:context="emit.dev.androideatit.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Also, there is a typo in styles.xml.

**Resources** --> resources

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. However, it appears that regardless of which layout I use, it still gives me the element error. Also, the resources typo was corrected.

Comment: It seems from the images that your project is not built successfully. Try to build your app first and then check once. Select Clean Project in Built menu and then Make project. If still it does not build successfully, select Invalidate caches/restart in File menu.

Comment: Hello, It appears that that didn't work either. Is it possible that its my build.gradle that is the problem?